# Why does my sound sometimes stop working in Vista?

Tags: audio, windows-vista

I have a pc running Vista sp2 and I don't like to reboot very often, but occasionally I have to restart the Windows Audio Service because the sound just doesn't work any more. I am using the onboard audio.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar problem, described by Rafael Rivera [here](http://www.withinwindows.com/2008/05/07/sonic-focus-speedily-fixes-leaky-windows-vista-audio-drivers/). I fixed the problem by installing newer drivers for my onboard audio chipset; try checking if you have the most up-to-date drivers (maybe check the manufacturer homepage). At least the link will better explain what is probably happening.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my on board sound, but mine is hardware related.

I've determined it's hardware related because putting in a headphone jack into the headphone port on the front of the machine and taking it out (including sometimes jiggling the connection) helps to reset an issue the hardware is experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues - it turned out to be a faulty audio driver. Find what on-board audio device you have and download the latest driver.

If it's any consolation, in Windows 7, all you'll have to do is right-click the speaker icon, and Windows will solve the problem for you (i.e. restart the Windows Audio Service and run through a series of steps to correct the issue).

Answer (score 0):

After a CHKDSK the message audiosrv.dll is deleted and later it was saved in another file.
But since then my sound is not working anymore.
I have tried almost everything to get it back working.
I even downloaded the dll myself, but still nothing
Is the connection also in the registry broken?
I don't know since I don't dabble too much in there.
There is the option of going back to factory settings, but that's my ultimate solution.
What the .... is going on with my laptop, always problems with it